# SpringBoot JPA Specification cannot check wheter a field contains a string

Tags: spring-boot, jpa

I recently started to use Specifications with SpringBoot and JPA and I'm stuck with a very simple query. I have an entity called UserAccount with a String field "mail". I would check whether it contains a value. This is what I wrote:

```
public class UserAccountSpecs
{
   public static Specification<UserAccount> getUserAccountByData(String username, String 
  mail)
   {
     return new Specification<UserAccount>()
     {
      @Override
      public Predicate toPredicate(Root<UserAccount> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder) 
      {
          Predicate predicate=criteriaBuilder.conjunction();
                        
          if(mail!=null && !mail.isEmpty())
          {                   
            predicate = criteriaBuilder.and(predicate, 
                     criteriaBuilder.like(root.get("mail").as(String.class), mail)); 
          }
          //extends the query by checking username if specified
          return predicate;
      }
  };
}    
}
```

But I always get no results. I also tried to use "criteriaBuilder.equals" in order to verify that the email exactly matches the value with analogous results, hence the problem concerns how I understood the use of CriteriaBuilder.

Comment: javadoc for `CriteriaBuilder#disjunction` is: "Create a disjunction (with zero disjuncts). **A disjunction with zero disjuncts is false**."

Comment: I changed it with "conjunction". Now I think that criteriaBuilder.like as written does not check whether the mail contains the passed string. Any tip?

Comment: String matching is the solution. Thanks!